# Can we use some tool to send cisco command to multiple ip address?

Tags: networking, command-line-interface, cisco

Can we use cli to send cisco command to multiple ip address ?
example i have cisco's switch (it's can access via telnet) 20 units i need to send 1 command to all switch and save (192.168.1.10-30)

could you share example or idea thank you in advance.

Comment: There is at least one terminal application that will allow you to make connections to multiple network devices in different tabs , then you can send the same command to all the tabs (devices) at the same time, or to only one tab (device) as the default method. Unfortunately, product recommendations are off-topic here, and this entire question is off-topic here because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

For sure, you have some tools like "MobaXTerm" or "SuperPutty", you can open your 20 units, use the MultiExec option, so when you type in one tab, all other tabs will receive your commands in one time at all. But I recommend you learn about Ansible, to you start automate your tasks and you will get the same result.